# Saber quantas vezes projeto do gitub foi clonado

Tags: git, github

Estou com uma pequena questão a ser resolvida e preciso saber se existe alguma forma de identificar quantas vezes meu projeto que está no github foi `clonado`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Para saber quantas vezes o código fonte do seu repositório foi clonado em um determinado dia, bem como quantos usuários do GitHub (ou endereços IP anônimos) fizeram a clonagem, vai na aba *Traffic*, ela mostra um monte de informações sobre quem está visitando seu repositório na web.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja mais na [Documentação](https://help.github.com/articles/about-repository-graphs/#traffic)

Comment: Muito obrigado, era justamente isso que eu procurava.